# How can I add an apklib dependency to your android maven project?

Tags: android, maven, m2eclipse, android-maven-plugin, apklib

I have an android project which I am developing on eclipse and building with maven. I wanted to include a lib (apklib) in it, and similarly to other includes, I have tried appending the dependency to my pom in the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupID.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.name</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when trying to build it either from m2eclipse or from maven on the console, I would get an error

> (Failed to execute goal on project **projectName**: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project **project** Failure to find **apklib** in
>   **repo** was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of **repo** has elapsed or
>   updates are forced)

saying that this dependency could not be found even if I can see the dependency in my .m2 directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, but since I found it through an example trying to demonstrate something else, rather than a Q&A (and I did not find it easily in the maven-android-plugin project,) I decided to share it here with the hope it can help someone.

The solution was just to set my dependency type to apklib in this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupID.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact.name</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This no longer works for android 23.0.1 or 23.1.0 as its now type aar. However type aar does not work. Any suggestions?