# Android Maven SDK Deployer

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I need to include appcompat-v7 in a maven build. Please note this is a question about a library with resources and not a jar. It's currently an aar artifact. The documentations on the SDK Deployer does not cover version 23.1.0 or version 23.0.1.   I need to know what dependency needs to be in pom to include the compatibility library.  Its either aar or apklib, and or also the include of a jar file as well.  If anyone has got this working I would appreciate it if you would share the correct pom dependency.  This problem appears to have been solved here:
 [How can I add an apklib dependency to your android maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354907/how-can-i-add-an-apklib-dependency-to-your-android-maven-project?rq=1)

but this solution expressed in latest Android would be:

```
         <dependency>
             <groupId>android.support</groupId>
             <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
             <version>23.1.0</version>
             <type>apklib</type>
         </dependency>
```

This does not work now because apklib is not what is there. It is aar and changing type to aar does not seem to work either. Resulting in lots of conflicts or missing classes or class conflicts.  I can think of no more commonly needed library from SDK Deployer than this. So could someone please answer the quesiton. In addition, I think the documentation of the deployer should reflect current versions, not just versions that are years old. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the SDK deployer references all dependencies that are custom created in addition to the ones from the repositories of the SDK itself. You can run the deployer and deploy all the components into a repository manager like Nexus and then search there or you can browse the local file system repository in ~/.m2/repository. For example look in the directory ~/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/

In your case you probably want to use something like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
  <version>23.1.1</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

This is all mentioned in the docs. And the deployer is open source and I do accept pull requests ;-)